# JScript IDE with autocomplete for COM objects created with ActiveXObject () function

Tags: com, autocomplete, activex, jscript, activexobject

Is there a JScript IDE with autocomplete for COM objects created with `ActiveXObject()` function?

i.e. so that after typing the following piece of code the IDE would display the list of methods / properties of the ExcelApp object:

```
var ExcelApp = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
ExcelApp.
```

The only thing I've found was JsEdit, but I guess it got discontinued some time ago. I've also tested Visual Studio and JetBrains Webstorm, but couldn't make the autocomplete functionality to work.

Answer (score 2):

(Disclaimer: I am the author of the project in question.)

I use [ts-activex-gen](https://github.com/zspitz/ts-activex-gen) to generate the Typescript definition files for a given ActiveX library, and any Typescript-supporting editor (I use [Visual Studio Community](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/community/) with the [Typescript](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48593) plugin).

You won't be able to write Typescript directly in your `.wsf` or `.hta`, but you can use script tags to reference the outputted Javascript files.

---

In Visual Studio Code, setting `allowJs` to `true` within `tsconfig.json` will display Intellisense based on Typescript definition files not only while editing Typescript, but even while editing plain Javascript files.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I've gotten around this is to make my own wrapper for the methods most commonly used.  I'm on Visual Studio 2012.  I include all of the js files as script tags in my wsf file, and then the intellisense in Visual Studio picks them up.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that [SAPIEN's PrimalScript](https://www.sapien.com/software/primalscript) does this.

Note that you if your Excel app is 32bit, you'll need the 32-bit version of the application (unfortunately I don't have the 32-bit version of PrimalScript installed at the moment to show you).

From https://www.sapien.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=9421#p51078

> [image]
>
> Please note that the 64 bit version of PrimalScript cannot see 32 bit COM objects and vice versa.
> The above screenshot was created on Windows 7 with the 32 bit version of PrimalScript 2015 and Office 2010 32 Bit.

The quote shows the behavior for VBScript, but the output should be basically identical for JScript.

Comment: Please elaborate how this answers the question.

Comment: @Yunnosch Ah, I misread the question. I fixed the answer -- thanks for the heads up.